# Where can I find a map control for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, geolocation, maps, gis

I am trying to build an option in a application that let user see a map. This map must be editable, and tag enabled. It should also be possible to see sub regions in different colors, and highlight the one under the mouse.

Comment: Eleven years later & we now have  a site for such questions - https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

TGlobe is good one, but hasn't updated since 2004, If you need more than showing a map, and build a GIS like application I suggest use one of these:

1. [TatukGIS](http://www.tatukgis.com/Home/home.aspx) (very powerful GIS Components and writing as Native VCL).
2. [CartoVCL](http://cartovcl.com/).
3. [MapObjects](http://www.esri.com/software/mapobjects/index.html) (the Leading GIS Company, but the components are ActiveX).

Comment: We use TatukGIS (in VB6 though), fairly good experiences with them.

Comment: I second TatukGIS - we've been using Tatuk for years. Both their ActiveX edition through VB6 and their .NET edition with C#.  Our only complaint is poor documentation.

Comment: TatukGis is good product. But if you also need data you may add a TWEBBroser point to a mapservice like openstreetmap/googlemap

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a component named [TGlobe](https://web.archive.org/web/20090201162449/http://tglobe.com/), which I've never used. 
The website has not been up dated since 2009, and it is no longer available as of 2013.

> - TGlobe 5 is a VCL component for Delphi 5, 6, 7, 2005 plus CBuilder 5 and 6.
> - TGlobe displays a Globe of the Earth which can be rotated, panned and zoomed in realtime. The globe contains map data in the form of Point, Lines and Polygons.
> - TGlobe organises map data into Layers. These layers can be nested together to build up a hierachy of related layers.
> - TGlobe can switch between the 3D spherical view of the earth and Cartesian, Mercator or user defined projections.

[image]

Comment: Second link is now broken.

Comment: Hmmm - does anyone have these TGlobe components? The webpages are available on the wayback machine, but not the downloads. I collect Delphi GIS components, old and new, (and am one of the developers of [CartoVCL](http://cartovcl.com) mentioned above)